# Facebook FB.login dialog fails with error

Tags: facebook, authentication

```
New to Facebook apps, developing a test app using JavaScript:
```

1. I am logged-in to Facebook as the app administrator (regular user).
2. I get to the point where FB.getLoginStatus returns response.status === 'not_authorized'.

   1. I call FB.login.
   2. I get a popup saying "An error occurred. Please try again later."
   3. FB.login calls back with response.authResponse = null.
   4. The console log says "LOG: Could not find callback 1".

I get the same error in all browsers...
    Help?

```
Here is the relevant code - I replaced actual strings by ######:

<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>

var init_status = 1;
var login_status = 1;
var signedRequest = ' ';

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '######', // App ID from the App Dashboard
    channelUrl : 'http://#####/channel.php', // Channel File for x-domain communication
    status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
    cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
    xfbml      : false  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
  });
  getLoginStatus();
};

// Load the SDK Asynchronously:
(function(d){
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
  ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));

call_proceed1_when_ready(); // wait for init_status > 1

function proceed1() {

  // Login the user and/or authenticate with app, if necessary:
  if (init_status > 2) {
    login ();
  } else {
    login_status = 2;
  }

  call_proceed2_when_ready(); // wait for login_status > 1

} //proceed1

function proceed2() {

  alert('DONE');

} //proceed2

////////////////
// FUNCTIONS: //
////////////////

function call_proceed1_when_ready () {
  if (init_status > 1) {
    proceed1();
  } else {
    setTimeout(call_proceed1_when_ready, 500); // 0.5 second
  }
}

function call_proceed2_when_ready () {
  if (login_status > 1) {
    proceed2();
  } else {
    setTimeout(call_proceed2_when_ready, 500); // 0.5 second
  }
}

function getLoginStatus() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      signedRequest = response.authResponse.signedRequest;
      init_status = 2;
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      init_status = 3;
    } else {
      init_status = 4;
    }
  });
}

function login() {
  FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
      login_status = 2;
    } else {
      login_status = 3;
    }
  });
}

</script>
```

Comment: Can you post some code?
Did you set app ID and app Secret ?

Comment: I edited the original post, adding code.

Comment: SOLVED.

Apparently this happens when you develop more than one app at the same time... I used the wrong appId on FB.init. After fixing it, the problem seems to be solved.

I would leave this "discussion" here for the sake of others experiencing similar behavior.

Comment: bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/630078357007816